# need a way to print a string in binary format?

Tags: java

I have a string. It contains some blank space. I don't know what's these blank space. They might be a space, or be a tab.. or sth else.

So I just want to print a string in binary format.

Also, how to use String.replace() to filter out some characters in binary format? Or I need to use some other kind of API to filter out the special characters in binary format.

for example, how to filter out chr(10) in a string. ( chr(10) means a Chang Line)

Just find out its reason:

I use these line to print what's this whitespace:

```
for (char ch : MyString.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.format("%H ", ch);
    }
```

I got it's result. It's "3000".

I checked UTF-8 table and found 3000 really looks a blank space.

Then I just use this code to remove this blank space:

```
MyString = MyString.replaceAll("\u3000", "");
```

Now everything become ok.

Thanks a lot for everyone's help!!

Comment: If you want to examine the numeric values of the characters it would probably be more effective to print in hex.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex. `\s` represents whitespace.

```
str.replace( "\\s+", "" );
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure this answers the question, since I don't exactly understand it.

Comment: This will remove line feeds, but also all other whitespace.

Comment: @DavidConrad, right he states "I don't know what's these blank space"

Comment: He wants to see what all the spaces are (all the characters, actually, in binary or hex), but he wants to filter out the line feeds ("how to filter out chr(10)").

Comment: Thank you all. Just find out the solution: I used this code to show what's this whitespace:     for (char ch : MyString.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.format("%H ", ch);
    } . Then I found it's "3000".  I checked UTF-8 table and find 3000 is really a whitespace like blank.  Then I used MyString = MyString.replaceAll("\u3000", "");.  At last, I got correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Use String.toCharArray(), loop over all the char, use String.toString((int) char), 16) to get a hex value. Separate with " " or "," for readability.